# Is it possible to retrieve thematic layer information for a Layer in Mapbasic?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I found this code

```
 windowinfo(FrontWindow(), WIN_INFO_CLONEWINDOW)
```

This function gives information (mapbasic) about the front Map window which can be used to regenerate the map.

> Is there any function in mapbasic 10.0 function that gives code that can be used to generate a
>   thematic layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have the code that separates each shade layer  and puts it into array. Although it doesn't work right now as it is just part of code it would give a glimpse of how it can be solved. It is solution form **James S** answer but now limited to single shade statement.

```
Function shadeInfo(ByVal shadeInfoText As String) As String
    CALL layersNoThematic

    Dim initLayer As Integer
    Dim tempShadeLayer As Integer
    Dim isFirstLoop As Logical
    Dim shadeInfoArraySize As Integer
    isFirstLoop = True
    initLayer = 0
    shadeInfoArraySize = 1

    Dim i, j As Integer 
    Dim m,n As Integer 
    m=1
    Dim sText, sShadeText As String 
    Dim sRec As String 
      CLS 
      sText = shadeInfoText 
      j= Len( sText )
      print "TOTAL LENGTH OF SHADE INFO : " &Len( sText ) 
      n = 1 
      Do While n < j 
        sRec = GetNextRecord( sText, n )
        ' look for the start of the shade clause 
        If Left$(sRec, 5) = "shade" Then 
          ' gather up all the lines in the shade clause 
          Do While n < j
            sShadeText = sShadeText + sRec 
            sRec = GetNextRecord( sText, n ) 
            If n > j THEN
              sShadeText = sShadeText + sRec 
            End If
            ' all lines in the shade clause after the first start with a space. 
            If Left$(sRec,1) <> " " OR n > j Then 
              ReDim shadeAndLayerStringArray(shadeInfoArraySize)
              shadeAndLayerStringArray(m).shadeString = sShadeText
              'print "This is shade information : " + chr$(10) +sShadeText +chr$(10)
               tempShadeLayer = DeformatNumber$(Mid$(sShadeText,7,InStr(1,sShadeText," w")-6))
                  IF initLayer > tempShadeLayer THEN
                    'print "Layer No Is :" & tempShadeLayer & chr$(10)
                    shadeAndLayerStringArray(m).LayerName =   layerNameFromOrder(tempShadeLayer)
                  ElseIF initLayer < tempShadeLayer THEN
                    IF isFirstLoop THEN
                      'print "Layer No Is :" & tempShadeLayer & chr$(10)
                      shadeAndLayerStringArray(m).LayerName =  layerNameFromOrder(tempShadeLayer)
                      isFirstLoop = FALSE
                    Else
                      'print "Layer No Is :" & initLayer & chr$(10)
                      shadeAndLayerStringArray(m).LayerName =  layerNameFromOrder(initLayer)
                    End IF

                  IF Left$(sRec,5) <> "shade" THEN
                         'print "Quiting Application"
                         Exit Sub 
                  ELSE
                       shadeInfoArraySize = shadeInfoArraySize +1
                       initLayer = tempShadeLayer
                       'print "SHADE ARRAY SIZE : " &  shadeInfoArraySize
                       sShadeText = ""  
                        m= m+1
                      'print "ARRAY M :" & m        

                  END IF
                END IF  

            End If 
          Loop 
        End If      
      Loop 
      For i=1 TO ubound(shadeAndLayerStringArray)
        print shadeAndLayerStringArray(i).layerName
        print shadeAndLayerStringArray(i).shadeString
      Next
End Function

Function GetNextRecord( ByVal sText As String, n As Integer ) As String 
    ' Read the next record in a body of text 
    Dim m As Integer 
    Dim sRec As String 
      m = InStr( n, sText, ""+Chr$(10)) 
      sRec = Mid$( sText, n, (m-n+1)) 
      n = m+1 
      GetNextRecord = sRec 

End Function
```

I shall post full working code later :)

Answer (score 2):

There is an answer on the [MapInfo-L](http://groups.google.com/group/mapinfo-l/browse_thread/thread/95a63d0784eaa85/58b5c23cba5215dc?lnk=gst&q=thematic#58b5c23cba5215dc). It appears there is no easy way to do this.

You would have to find the information from either a workspace file or a Clone window statement and then create a new shade statement on the layer you want to apply it to.

The link has some code on how to get the information.

Comment: nice answer +1 but most of the code in mapinfo-L extracts only first shade statement.

Answer (score 0):

From MapBasic Reference Guide:

> The Shade statement creates a thematic map layer and adds the layer to
>   an existing Map window. The Shade statement corresponds to MapInfo
>   Professional's Map > Create Thematic Map menu item.

Comment: Is there possibility to get information about thematic layer already created and apply this to other layer this is my question actually. :)

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread your question. As far as I know it can't be done. Though it is possible to save the thematic stylings as a template and then apply them to a different layer I don't think you can do this programmatically. If you find a way please let me know!

Comment: Ofcourse I will :)